# how to create custom command that would run my npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line

So i made a npm package called `chat` in nodejs, which is not yet hosted on npm. Now it has two files, `server.js` and `client.js`. Earlier, I used to run `node server.js` and `node client.js` to run two files.

I want to use a custom command, say `chat server` and `chat client` to run `server.js` and `client.js` respectively. How should I do this?

I have been searching on Google for this but got no helpful results.

Any answers are appreciated

Comment: Starting point: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run custom commands you need to add `bin` property in `package.json` file as below:

```bash
"bin": {
  "chat server": "./server.js",
  "chat client": "./client.js"
}
```

Then you need to run the `npm link` command in the project directory to create a symbolic link between your package and the global NPM executable, allowing you to execute commands directly.

Then make sure that your files referenced in `bin` property starts with `#!/usr/bin/env node`.

**If the custom commands contain two or more separate words, must be within quotes to execute them.**

The `'chat server'` command will run the `server.js` file while the `'chat client'` command will run the `client.js` file.

Another approach is to add `scripts` property in `package.json` file as below:

```bash
"scripts": {
  "chat:server": "node server.js",
  "chat:client": "node client.js"
}
```

The `npm run chat:server` command will run the `server.js` file while the `npm run chat:client` command will run the `client.js` file.

I recommend you read the NPM documentation regarding bin and scripts:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#bin
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#scripts

Comment: Okay this is for the future viewer for  the answer. It took me a lot of experiments with my own project to find this. (1) Each file that is executed must start with `#!/usr/bin/env node` .  (2) custom command must not contain two or more separate words, and if they do must be run within quotes like `chat host`.  @APN Carmine, i would request you to edit the answer as it contains some inaccurate info . Thanks again for answering me.

Comment: Done, I hope I helped you! I upvoted your post!